# Redundant query trigger when creating a graph?

Tags: arangodb

whenever I try to create a new graph with 700.000 to 2 Mio edges, it takes a long time. I observed due to the great new feature in the API

```
 /_api/query/current
```

that possibly the graph creation triggers automatically some kind of cache loading, but twice?

```
[
  {
    "id": "70",
    "query": "FOR x IN GRAPH_VERTICES(@graph, {}) SORT RAND() LIMIT @limit RETURN x",
    "started": "2015-03-31T19:06:59Z",
    "runTime": 41.95919394493103
  },
  {
    "id": "71",
    "query": "FOR x IN GRAPH_VERTICES(@graph, {}) SORT RAND() LIMIT @limit RETURN x",
    "started": "2015-03-31T19:06:59Z",
    "runTime": 41.95719385147095
  }
]
```

Is this correct. Is there a more efficient way?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I also observe that SORT RAND() will always be used, even when I deactivate the checkbox "start with random vertex". This setting will also not be stored.

Comment: Each change in the setting fires a new (RANDOM) load. Even when I have  defined a filter on a concrete object.

Comment: It seems that each time the whole graph will be recalculated. Is there a way to define a sub graph which filters edges/nodes to those I am interested in for the visualization? Where can I define the @limit? How can I replace "SORT RAND()" by the starting node?

Comment: It looks like the above query is issued by the graph viewer in the web interface. Will have a look.

Comment: Yes, it's created by the graph viewer which I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

The graph viewer issued the mentioned `RAND()` query two times:
- one instance is fired to determine a random vertex from the graph
- the other instance is fired to determine the attributes of some random vertices of the graph, in order to populate the search input field

The AQL that was used by the graph viewer was inefficient. It build a big list, sorted it randomly and returned 1 (first query) or 10 (second query) documents from it. This has been fixed in commit [c28575f202a58d5c93e6c36883effda48c2a7159](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/commit/c28575f202a58d5c93e6c36883effda48c2a7159) so it's much more efficient now.

The fix will be included in the next build (i.e. 2.5.2).

Comment: Thank you, that sounds good, and I am looking forward to 2.5.2 (anyway :-). Do you see any chance to influence the "starting query" even more? One typical problem occurs whenever you want to visualize only a small part of a graph (e.g. due to performance still). The only way I see now is to duplicate the vertexes (partially) and to recalculate the edges (as the ids are different in the duplicated vertex collections), and then to use the smaller graph in the vizualization. Well, not too much ease-of-use up to now :-)

Comment: The graph viewer will by default pick a random vertex when opened and display it along with all its connected edges. With the above commit applied, picking a random vertex should not be expensive anymore. A problem may still occur if the selected vertex contains many connected edges, and displaying all of them would be expensive. But I am not sure if I understand your suggestion yet and how it would help. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Yes, sure. I test Arango for scenarios with huge graphs, e.g. 20 Mio edges/nodes. For visualization purposes, I do not want to use all of them, as a) the net is to huge for the technology, and b) I want to focus on a subset of the net for the vizualization/graphical navigation. so my idea is to define filter for nodes/edges to be used in the graph viewer. I could do that if I could influence the loading AQL statement (defining filters) ... which is currently not possible.

Comment: I gave it a try and copied collections in order to reduce the graph I'd like to vizualize. But well, that's very inflexible and in fact also time-consuming.

Comment: by the way, I see I did not yet understand why this function GRAPH_VERTICES is needed for the Vizualization, as the module always starts with one vertex. When I click onto a vertex, it's neighbours, defined be it's edges, wil be opened. I wonder if this could not be done by querying them on-the-fly (wihtout inital precalculation of the whole graph) e.g. by using the EDGE function or something similar ...

Comment: re GRAPH_VERTICES: it was used for picking a random vertex from the graph. This was the cause of the inefficiency, as GRAPH_VERTICES will build an array of all vertices. After that, a random vertex from the array was chosen. As mentioned, this has been fixed for 2.5.2 so that GRAPH_VERTICES won't be used anymore. Instead, we'll be picking a random vertex from each collection from the graph (at most one per collection), shuffle the array and return one. That should be very efficient.

Comment: re filtering: I understood the requirement is to define filter conditions for edges and/or vertices to be displayed in the graph viewer. I think this would make sense for several other use cases, too. Would you mind opening a feature request for this in our Github issue tracker? I think that place will be more appropriate than the SO comments.